# Converting ArcMap shapefile with labels to KML (labels retained)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, kml

I am having problem i converting a shapefile with label to Google Earth KML using ArcGIS Desktop 10.1. I would like to convert a shapefile with label into KML wherein the label is retained in KML and readable. I have tried to convert the shapefile but the label in kml is unreadable.

[image].

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be encountering a known limit when converting line and polygon labels to KML.

This is documented as Technical Article 43000: [Labels do not appear in Google Earth after converting to KML](http://support.esri.com/em/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/43000):

> This is a known limit. Google Earth only displays labels for point
>   features (placemarks). To display labels for line or polygon features
>   in Google Earth, midpoints or centroids for those feature classes must
>   be created as a point layer in ArcMap and imported as a separate layer
>   to Google Earth.

Workarounds using Advanced level, as well as Basic and Standard level licenses, are documented in that Technical Article.